# Center both Image and text

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm working on a report where on wich page I need to show an image next to a text at the center. The problem is that I don't previously know the length of the text. Is there a way to acheive this.

Here is an image to make it clearer:

[image]
and here how it should look :
[image]

Comment: is that blue bar fixed size?

Comment: Then use position:fixed for the item "inovpc" and define a left value to center. Post related source part.

Comment: There are two characters in Webdings font that look sorta like your image. Just saying... :)